# Software for pronunciation training with my own sound files

Tags: pronunciation, software

So, let's say I have several mp3 files with native speaker's pronunciation.
What I need is playing one of them, pronounce after it and so on with the next sound pattern. Then play all the sequence and look for my errors.

Currently I can do it with Audacity, but it takes rather long.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is probably an offtopic, but your question is basically about manual advance through the playlist (e.g., stopping after each track, needs to press a key to re-play or advance to the next). Only several players have this feature. [WinAmp/Windows](http://www.winamp.com/): Prefs - Playlist - "Manual playlist advance"; also check [One Track Mind/iOS](http://www.houseofpung.net/otm/) and [BlueMuse/Android](http://androidforums.com/app-game-announcements/287077-app-bluemuze-bluetooth-wi-fi-music-playlist-transfer.html) (long press on a track)

Comment: [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) is also a handy and free phonetics program, though I think it'll _definitely_ be overkill for your needs.

Comment: @bytebuster , I'm sorry if I've not expressed it clearly, but I need the app to grab my own voice and play all the sequence, which includes native speaker's pronunciation and my own.

Comment: This question would be on-topic on the [Software Recommendations beta site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and would be on-topic on the [proposed Languages site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61823), but I don't think it's about linguistics per se, it's about language learning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[yourpronunciationlab](http://www.yourpronunciationlab.com) can do that. This app automatically replays the sample, records your repetition, replays the sample and the repetition together then the process starts from the beginning.